# fullcalendar + momentjs throwing exception when using session

Tags: meteor, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar plugin and meteor together.

Around about the time meteor went to 0.8.1 and fullcalendar went to 2.1.0 i started receiving an error when placing a fullcalendar calEvent object into a meteor Session. I am doing a simple click on a calendar event and storing the current object in a meteor session object.

```
Session.set('Calendar_currentSelected', calEvent);
```

The calEvent object contains some simple fields but primarily the error seems to relate to the Start and End date objects as these are embedded objects:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in moment JS
```

Any ideas?

Comment: And how moment JS is involved in this procedure?

Comment: calEvent object has a few moment objects in it - One for Start Date and one for End Date

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `calEvent` object is not serializable. Session routines always try to turn object into string using `JSON.stringify` behind the scenes. I can see two solutions here. You can either make sure that your `calEvent` event is serializable by turning each `moment` object it contains into `Date`, or you can consider using `ReactiveVar` (look [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#reactivevar_pkg)), which allows you to store any type of object and preserve reactivity, though it's a little bit difficult to use that `Session`.